# split file into multiple files (by columns)

Tags: bash, awk, split, cut

I have a file data.txt in which there are 200 columns and rows (a square matrix). So, i have been trying to split my file into 200 files, each of then with one of the column from the big data file. These where my two attempts employing cut and awk, however i don't understand why is not working.

```
NM=`awk 'NR==1{print NF-2}' < file.txt`
echo $NM

for (( i=1; i = $NM; i++ ))
do
echo $i 
cut -f ${i} file.txt > tmpgrid_0${i}.dat
#awk '{print '$i'}'  file.txt > tmpgrid_0${i}.dat
done
```

Any suggestions?.

EDIT: Thank you very much to all of you. All answers were valid but i cannot vote to all of them.

Comment: Probably `for... i<=$NM`

Comment: And `awk '{print $'$i'}' file.txt`

Comment: And `NM=$(awk 'NR==1{print NF-2}' file.txt)` without the redirection as awk reads the parameter as a file anyway, and also using $() in place of backticks which are inferior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise my comments, I suggest something like this (untested as I have no sample file):

```
NM=$(awk 'NR==1{print NF-2}' file.txt)
echo $NM

for (( i=1; i <= $NM; i++ ))
do
   echo $i 
   awk '{print $'$i'}'  file.txt > tmpgrid_0${i}.dat
done
```

Comment: Is there the possibility to do the same for instance with NR=$'$i' ??

Comment: You probably want `NR=='$i`

Comment: I was trying to do the same but i couldn't succeed with that option

`var=$(awk 'NR==$'$i'{print $2}' file2.txt)`

Comment: Remove the `$` after `NR==` if you mean you want to print the 7th line if `i` is 7.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=5;i++){name=FILENAME"_"i;print $i> name}}' your_file
```

Tested with 5 columns:

```
> cat temp
PHE  5  2 4 6
PHE  5  4 6 4
PHE  5  4 2 8
TRP  7  5 5 9
TRP  7  5 7 1
TRP  7  5 7 3
TYR  2  4 4 4
TYR  2  4 4 0
TYR  2  4 5 3
> nawk '{for(i=1;i<=5;i++){name=FILENAME"_"i;print $i> name}}' temp
> ls -1  temp_*
temp_1
temp_2
temp_3
temp_4
temp_5
> cat temp_1
PHE
PHE
PHE
TRP
TRP
TRP
TYR
TYR
TYR
>
```

Comment: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){name=FILENAME"_"i;print $i> name}}' a.txt  To more generic.I also came up with this way..Nice!

Comment: I like this solution because it should be more efficient on big files, as opposed to solutions running a command in a for loop. Bonus: you get a fine control over which field you write to which files. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `tr` and `split`

```
< file.txt tr ' ' '\n' | split -nr/200
```

This assumes that the file is space delimited, but the tr command could be tweaked as appropriate for any delimiter. Essentially this puts each entry on its own line, and then uses split's round robin version to write each 200th line to the same file.

```
paste -d' ' x* | cmp - file.txt
```

verifies that it worked if split is writing files with an `x` prefix.

I got this solution from Reuti on the coreutils mailing list.